# How to upload image, which is not saved on the device to the dropbox account?(IOS)

Tags: objective-c, ios, image, dropbox

Dropbox restClient saves only files. So i want to save the image in local folder first and then to upload it, as a result it saves file, but it is corrupted.

```
NSString *localPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Info" ofType:@"plist"];
NSString *jpegFilePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/test.jpeg",localPath];
NSData *data2 = [NSData dataWithData:UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0f)];
[data2 writeToFile:jpegFilePath atomically:YES];

NSString *filename = @"test.jpeg";

NSString *destDir = @"/";
[[self restClient] uploadFile:filename toPath:destDir
                withParentRev:nil fromPath:localPath];
```

**I am an idiot, solved**

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *path = [[paths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingString:@"test.jpg"];

NSData * data = [NSData dataWithData:UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0f)];
[data writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
[self.restClient uploadFile:@"test.jpg" toPath:@"/" withParentRev:nil fromPath:path];
```

Comment: Is the result corrupted as in broken with the correct size or wrong size or empty or...?

Comment: Size equals:1,012 bytes ,so its wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you  will have to call DBRestClient methods from the main thread or a thread that has a run loop. Otherwise the delegate methods will not be called.

what you will have to do is first alloc init yoir DBRestClient object then make it's delegate self and then you can easily upload your file.below is an example

```
NSString *destDir = @"/";
restClient = [[DBRestClient alloc] initWithSession:[DBSession sharedSession]];
restClient.delegate = self;

[restClient uploadFile:yourfilename toPath:destDir withParentRev:nil fromPath:sourcepath];
```

Happy Coding!!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

You can't save into the bundle. You should use documents or cache folder:

```
 NSString *documentsDirectory = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
```

Comment: I tried this already. It saves file ,but then appears error: WARNING] DropboxSDK: Unable to upload folders (/Users.....)